# Change price and calculate by quantity flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to change the price according to the quantity contained in the item, but I get a problem like this where the price is not displayed. price in widget text RP not show from response, the price that should appear is the price that appears in the response log run console, Now it only shows - and also the price doesn't change

[image: Cart Model]

[image: http get]

[image: Widget price]

[image: counter tap]

[image: log response]

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:sobatprambanan_app/model/cart.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class CartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  // const CartPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  // String img;
  String name;
  // String description;
  String price;
  String deviceId;
  String unit;
  String quantity;

  CartPage({Key key, this.name, this.price, this.deviceId, this.unit, this.quantity}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CartPageState createState() => _CartPageState();
}

class _CartPageState extends State<CartPage> {

  String deviceUniqueID = "Unknown";
  loadSharedPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      deviceUniqueID = (prefs.getString("deviceID")??"");
      print("Ini line 30: $deviceUniqueID");
    });
  }
  List<Cart> dataCart = [];
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getDataItems() async {
     var urlGetTransaksi = "http://192.168.0.13:8891/api/Transaksi/";
     SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     String salesmanID = prefs.getString("deviceID");
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(urlGetTransaksi+salesmanID));
    List<Cart> listItems = (json.decode(response.body)as List).map((e) => Cart.fromJson(e)).toList();
    for (int i = 0 ; i <listItems.length; i++){
      int number = listItems[i].quantity;
      _count.add(number);
    }
    this.setState(() {
      print(response);
      print("Ini 28: ${response.body}");
      print(listDataCartItems);
      dataCart = listItems;
      // result;
    });
  }
  List<Widget> listDataCartItems = [];

  RefreshController _refreshController =
  RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);

  List data;
  void _onRefresh() async{
    // monitor network fetch
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    getDataItems();
    // if failed,use refreshFailed()
    _refreshController.refreshCompleted();
  }

  void _onLoading() async{
    // monitor network fetch
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    // if failed,use loadFailed(),if no data return,use LoadNodata()
    data.add((data.length+1).toString());
    if(mounted)
      setState(() {
        getDataItems();
      });
    _refreshController.loadComplete();
  }

 List<int> _count = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    // getDataItems();
    loadSharedPrefs();
    getDataItems();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.chevron_left,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 11.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "My Order",
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .display1
                        .apply(fontWeightDelta: 2, color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5.0,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SmartRefresher(
                      enablePullDown: true,
                      enablePullUp: false,
                      header: WaterDropHeader(),
                      footer: CustomFooter(
                        builder: (BuildContext context,LoadStatus mode) {
                          Widget body;
                          if(mode==LoadStatus.idle) {
                            body = Text("pull up load");
                          }
                          else if(mode==LoadStatus.loading){
                            body =  CupertinoActivityIndicator();
                          }
                          else if(mode == LoadStatus.failed){
                            body = Text("Load Failed!Click retry!");
                          }
                          else if(mode == LoadStatus.canLoading){
                            body = Text("release to load more");
                          }
                          else{
                            body = Text("No more Data");
                          }
                          return Container(
                            height: 55.0,
                            child: Center(child:body),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                      controller: _refreshController,
                      onRefresh: _onRefresh,
                      onLoading: _onLoading,
                      child: new ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: dataCart == null ? 0 : dataCart.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return new Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                            child: Card(
                              elevation: 3,
                              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      "assets/images/promo1.png",
                                      height: 50,
                                      width: 50,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Text(
                                      dataCart[index].itemName??"",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Rp. ${dataCart[index].price}"??"",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Center(
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 5,
                                      child: Divider(
                                        thickness: 1,
                                        color: Colors.orange,
                                        indent: 5,
                                        endIndent: 5,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  //Ini row button
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                      //menambah quantity
                                      Center(
                                        child: GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _count[index] += 1;
                                              dataCart[index].price*=_count[index];
                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                              border: Border.all(),
                                            ),
                                            child: Icon(Icons.add,size: 12,),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Center(
                                        child: Container(
                                          height: 60,
                                          child: VerticalDivider(
                                            thickness: 2,
                                            color: Colors.orange,
                                            endIndent: 20,
                                            indent: 5,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Center(
                                        child: Container(
                                          height: 30,
                                          child: InkWell(
                                              child: Text(
                                                _count[index].toString()??"",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              onTap: () {}),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Center(
                                        child: Container(
                                          height: 60,
                                          child: VerticalDivider(
                                            thickness: 2,
                                            color: Colors.orange,
                                            endIndent: 20,
                                            indent: 5,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      //mengurangi quantity
                                      GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _count[index]-= 1;
                                            dataCart[index].price -=_count[index];
                                          });
                                        },
                                        child: Container(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                            border: Border.all(),
                                          ),
                                          child: Icon(Icons.remove,size: 12,),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              color: Colors.grey[100],
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Payment",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                      child: ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ...List.generate(1, (i) {
                            return Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    "**** 4832",
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .title
                                        .apply(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  Spacer(),
                                  Text(
                                    "\$25.99",
                                    style:
                                    Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.apply(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Image.asset("assets/images/mastercard.png"),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 15.0,
                              ),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                              child: Icon(Icons.add),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Total Price",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "RP. 20.000.000",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Text(
                        "Confirm Payment",
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .button
                            .apply(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      color: Colors.green,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your codes as code snippet please

Comment: I have added the code